# Adding condition to ST_ClusterWithin?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Really don't know how to ask this right, but here it goes. How to add condition to ST_ClusterWithin to cluster data depending on distance AND some other attribute, like type of something?

> ST_ClusterWithin — Aggregate. Returns an array of
>   GeometryCollections, where each GeometryCollection represents a set of
>   geometries separated by no more than the specified distance.

Sample code from documentation:

```
WITH testdata AS
  (SELECT unnest(ARRAY['LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1)'::geometry,
               'LINESTRING (5 5, 4 4)'::geometry,
               'LINESTRING (6 6, 7 7)'::geometry,
               'LINESTRING (0 0, -1 -1)'::geometry,
               'POLYGON ((0 0, 4 0, 4 4, 0 4, 0 0))'::geometry]) AS geom)

SELECT ST_AsText(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 1.4))) FROM testdata;
```

Result:

```
st_astext
---------
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(0 0,1 1),LINESTRING(5 5,4 4),LINESTRING(0 0,-1 -1),POLYGON((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0)))
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(6 6,7 7))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Added info about the cluster sheme for multiple attributes*.
Since it is actually a window function, [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) should be the better option here:

```
SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(<geometry>, <max_dist_in_CRS_units>, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY <attr_a>, <attr_b>) AS cluster_id,
       *
FROM <your_table>
ORDER BY <attr_a>, <attr_b>, cluster_id
```

This returns the following  cluster sheme:

```
<attr_a>.A
    <attr_b>.A
        cluster_id.0
        cluster_id.1
        ...
    <atrr_b>.B
        cluster_id.0
        cluster_id.1
         ...
    ...
<attr_a>.B
    <attr_b>.A
        cluster_id.0
        cluster_id.1
        ...
    <atrr_b>.B
        cluster_id.0
        cluster_id.1
         ...
    ...
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this today. I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: @bKapusta you could even add more attributes by adding them as columns to the `PARTITION BY`. one note: this will assign *cluster_id*s from 0 - N for each *type* respectively, so to properly refer the clusters later, you'll need to relate the ids to the *type*.

Comment: I don't know if this is working for me. 
My problem: I have N geolocated measurements which needs to be grouped by distance, material type and line. 
I tryed:
`SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(gps_coordinates, 10, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY line, material_type) AS cluster_id, material_type, line, gps_coordinates
FROM measurements
ORDER BY cluster_id;`

Result is showing different material types and lines in same cluster. What am I missing here? And showing result only on very small distances like 0.00001.

Comment: as I said in the comment before, you will get *cluster_id* 0, 1, 2, N once for each *type*, so that the cluster definition actually has to be *type* + *cluster_id* to make sense. in your case, it will thus be *line* + *type* + *cluster_id*. try `... ORDER BY line, material_type, cluster_id;`

Comment: about the distance: the unit given to `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` as maximum distance (100 in above example) is not meters per se, but in units as defined by the CRS (so it will be degrees for geographical reference systems like WGS84). I update that in my answer. you will need to either cast *gps_coordinates* to *geography* type (from EPSG:4326) or transform to a projection that uses meter as unit

Comment: yes, you are right. I was expecting different result from cluster id. This is ok. Thank you @ThingumaBob

Comment: One more question, how can I save cluster_id to table? Can I do something like UPDATE measurements FROM (select from post) SET measurement.cluster_id = cluster_id

Comment: you could do `WITH cluster AS (*clustering_query*) UPDATE measurements SET cluster_id = cluster.cluster_id WHERE measurement.<id> = cluster.<id>`. also, to get a unique 'codified' cluster_id, you could use `concat(line::text || '.' || material_type:: text || '.' || cluster.cluster_id::text)` to get ids like 'line.material_type.1' as strings. good to read, bad to work with in PostGIS, consider this as an extra maybe...,)

Comment: I'm trying this in more ways, but in some reason cluster.id is not recognizing given table cluster. 
`missing FROM-clause entry for table "cluster"`
I did try SELECT *FROM cluster and it's working fine. All data is there, but in UPDATE, there's not. Any idea?

Comment: ah man, sorry, yes it has to be `WITH cluster AS (*clustering_query*) UPDATE measurements SET cluster_id = cluster.cluster_id FROM cluster WHERE measurement.<id> = cluster.<id>`...,)

Comment: yes I was trying to add FROM but in wrong place. Thanks man!